# Task Scheduler does not open Internet Explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have a bat file that is scheduled to run every 15 Minutes with the Windows 10 Task Scheduler. At some point it has to open a local html file in Internet Explorer.

```
START iexplore.exe -k C:\PATH\TO\FILE.html
```

That works perfectly when executing manually or using the option

```
only run when user is logged on
```

On some Systems that task started to fail recently with the error

```
The operator or administrator has refused the request(0x800710E0)
```

I tested some settings and the above problem seems to be resolved if i use credentials in the Task scheduler with the option

```
Run wether user is logged on or not
```

Now the task is completed successfully but the internet explorer does not open.

If i create a new .bat with this content:

> start iexplore.exe -k C:\file.html

and schedule it to run every 15 minutes it does not open the internet explorer if i use credentials, but it does if i use the "only run if user is logged on" option. Why is that ?